# mod_pagespeed ModPagespeedLoadFromFile ReGex not working

Tags: regex, mod-pagespeed

I have following directive in MPS config:

```
ModPagespeedLoadFromFile "^https?://www.(e|i)zi?aro(v|w)k(y|i).(cz|sk|pl)/static/" "/var/www/eZarovky/production/public/static/"
```

This RegExp should match all variation of our domains, eg.

```
https://www.eziarovky.sk
https://www.ezarovky.cz
```

etc, but it does not. According to PECL regex tester, it should match, however it does not.
With direct mapping, like following, everything is working.

```
ModPagespeedLoadFromFile "https://www.ezarovky.cz/static/" "/var/www/eZarovky/production/public/static/"
```

How this RegExp should look like, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ModPagespeedLoadFromFileMatch "^https?://www.(e|i)zi?aro(v|w)k(y|i).(cz|sk|pl)/static/" "/var/www/eZarovky/production/public/static/"
```

Should do.

Comment: Yes, meanwhile I used it, but your answer is correct :)
Just forgot to write it here..